# Do desktop applications use the same sandbox idea as ios does

Tags: iphone, windows, mobile, sandbox

I am writing a report on the differences of mobile development from developing a desktop application.  When writing an app for windows, are all contents of an app stored in an application sandbox like in ios or blackberry development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; even though environments like Java and .NET "sandbox" their applications, this only deals with the memory of the application while it's running and the sort of resources that can be accessed. iOS sandboxing completely isolates the application, *including its storage*.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

No so short answer: It depends on the platform you use. Software developed in java use a Sandbox while others don't

Comment: Even Java and .NET development do not use the same sort of sandboxing as iOS.

Comment: True. I didn't mean to say they were the same, just saying that Java also uses sandbox, but not the same type.

Answer (score 1):

It should also be pointed out that Mac OS X Lion provides a method of sandboxing that they encourage using, and will enforce using on apps available through the App Store. There are places to get a more in-depth description, like John Siracusa's great review on Ars Technica (or his extended discussion about it on the Hypercritical podcast), but generally it works on the idea of priveledge separation. Each process requests access to the priveledges it needs (e.g., reading from the file system or writing to a network socket). The program is then divided into multiple processes that each only use a small number of priveledges, so if one process is compromised it won't have enough priveledges to do serious damage. Definitely take a look at a more detailed description, it's a pretty interesting security feature.